# How to find Commons.web.mvc.precompiledviews.dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making the MVC4 work whit ClassLibrary, **visual studio 2012**

check this site: [a link](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the dll in this project if you download from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358360/NET-ASP-NET-MVC-plug-in-architecture-with-e)